# How should I respond to a request to join our team?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, email

A person would like to join our team and I also would like to have him on board. How might I respond to his request mail?

Would this be correct?

> *It'd be a great pleasure for us you joining our team.*

Answer (score 2):

> *It'd be a great pleasure to have you in our team and on the board.*

**I see two areas that perhaps need improvement.**

First, using *it'd* as a contraction for *it would* may be acceptable for conversation and for less formal communication; however, in this example, "great pleasure" introduces a degree of formality that clashes with "it'd". So, either expand the contraction:

> It would be a great pleasure to have you in our team and on the board.

or else use less formal language throughout:

> We'd love to have you as part of our team, and on our board.

---

Secondly, I don't like the preposition choice for *"**in** our team."* There may be some regional variations, but I believe the better word to use would be *"**on** our team."* It's true you can find instances of [both](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20team,on%20the%20team&year_start=1965&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,in%20the%20team;,c0;.t1;,on%20the%20team;,c0) in literature:

[image]

However, when we examine the instances of "in the team," the word *team* is sometimes being used as a qualifier, such as:

- The game was ready for dramatic changes in the **team concept**...
- In the **team meeting** the next day, her behavior was discussed.

So I'd be inclined to suggest:

> It would be a great pleasure to have you **on** our team and on the board.

However, while researching which would be the better preposition to use, I noticed that *in* was sometimes used in the medicine:

- The work of the nurses **in the team** also helped to ensure that concerns about the existing and future functioning capacities of patients...
- All the specialists **in the team** are sued. The patient can then ask for full repayment of all damages from all the specialists involved, and sometimes even the hospital.

so maybe "in" is in fact the better word to use, but it just sounds a little off to me because I don't work in a hospital.

<sub>NOTE: I don't know where I got the idea that this was for a hospital board – that seems to be part of an earlier answer, and not part of the O.P.'s question – so my last point may be irrelevant.</sub>

Comment: I'd like to bring it to your intention that the question was different in its original post and has been modified with an–imho–invalid edit.The sentence has been "It'd be a great pleasure for us you joining our team." The current ending came up in an edit. I do think the sentence that was phrased by OP should not have been edited or generally that such sentences shouldn't be edited at all(except typos or minor error that do not affect the question).And OP initially said that *he also likes him on board*. We don't know any context and if there's a board at all.

Comment: @Em1 - Thank you very much for bringing that to my attention. I hadn't noticed that on **the** board got added in as an edit, and I agree with you that it was invalid. It also shaped quite a bit of my answer, as there is a gigantic difference between welcoming someone "on board" and welcoming them "on the board."

Answer (score 0):

It is correct and some more suggestions are:

1.I'm so thankful for having you in my Team.

2.Thank you very much for your attention.

3.Thank you for your interest.

4.Thank you very much for participating in my team.

Comment: And what should be the reply to the suggestion number 1?

Answer (score 0):

> It'd be a great pleasure to have you in our team and on the board.

This is fine but there is better way to express it with 'thanks'. Also, after thanking, it's better to put some information about your service for what the user has joined.

> Thank you for your interest in joining our team and getting on the board. [Service/board's name] is committed to [service purpose]...and then...the ending note.

For example, if the team/board is of doctors, you may reply as mentioned below -

> Thank you for showing interest in joining our team and getting on the board. **Doctor's Board [hypothetical name]** is committed to provide genuine information about the diseases, new drugs and the latest research papers from renowned medical institutes. We shall review your application and get back to you soon.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, on two counts. (1) I don't see any problem with "great pleasure." It seems a good way to say what the O.P. wants to say, particularly in a formal context. (I wouldn't use it when answering a close associate, but it would be apt for a standard reply to someone I may not know very well.) (2) From the O.P.'s context, I don't think the deal has been finalized yet. Using language like "Thank you for joining our team" might be appropriate for a follow-on message after the person has officially accepted an offer, but it's not an appropriate response to an initial inquiry.

Comment: The O.P. didn't ask about the rest of the note, but just the first sentence. At any rate, including the purpose in such a generic manner makes it sound like a letter mailed to several people all at once, and not a personal letter.

Comment: @J.R. I did say that to make it better we may include the rest of the note. This can be the format sent to every person requesting for joining. I'm in an IT company and we have settled this as a format. When you run a group and have to respond hundreds of such requests, you certainly need it. Since the OP asked for replying the **mail**, I thought to answer this way.

Comment: We seem to have interpreted the O.P.'s question in two very different ways. I think both interpretations are valid, given the scant context provided by the O.P. This could be a single exchange of mails that should be kept very personal, or it could be a routine exchange with scores of applicants that requires a more canned reply.